# Delete in Map not deleting key that are objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have created a map object

```
var map_obj = new Map();
map_obj.set({'a':2, 'b':3}, {'c': 4});
```

now when i tried to use `.delete` operator

`map_obj.delete({'a':2, 'b':3})`

It is showing me false and key and value are not deleted. It can be that It is checking for object reference and creating a new object so can't find the equal object.
In MDN [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections#Object_and_Map_compared), it is said key can be of any type. So what's happening here and what would be the right way to delete the key ?

This is how delete process is defined in [es-6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map.prototype.delete)

Comment: The equality of the object key on entry is not the same as the key of the entry you're trying to delete, you could check that by simply doing `{'a':2, 'b':3} === {'a':2, 'b':3}`, does the key have to be an object? because otherwise you'll have to use variables to store the reference for each object key and that seems like a lot of hassle for such a simple task

Comment: maybe a `Map` is the wrong dtaa structure for this. you could take a nested map for each property as primitive key instead of an object.

Comment: see object take string as key and I managing a value that depends on three variables, thats why this look messy way.But still got better code readability through that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way, is to store the object reference to a variable.

```js
var map_obj = new Map(),
    object = { a: 2, b: 3 };

map_obj.set(object, {'c': 4});
console.log([...map_obj]);

map_obj.delete(object);
console.log([...map_obj]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you have only parts of the object then you need to find this object by comparing the object.

```js
var map_obj = new Map(),
    a = 2, b = 3,
    key;

map_obj.set({ a: 2, b: 3 }, {'c': 4});
console.log([...map_obj]);

key = Array.from(map_obj.keys()).find(o => o.a === a && o.b === b);

map_obj.delete(key);
console.log([...map_obj]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that when calling `map_obj.delete({'a':2, 'b':3})`, you call it with a new Object. Try :

```js
var map_obj = new Map();
x = {'a':2, 'b':3};
map_obj.set(x, {'c': 4});
//...
map_obj.delete(x);
```

Comment: what, if creation of the Map is totally unrelated to the deleting and there is no way of obtaining the original key object?

Comment: this way it will work, but in my requirement i will get value of a and b and based on that i have to set and delete the key. so this solution will fail at that time

Comment: @abby37 then don't use an object as key for your map. If you have two values a and b by which you want to map, I would suggest using a sting like `${a}#${b}` as a key.

Comment: @NikitaMalyschkin , please check my comments on Q. as this is requirement and single value depends on 3 variables, I can't find any other elegant way to implement this. Any suggestion will be welcome